# Excel Don't Change Data on Refresh

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have two sheets in an XLS file. 1st Sheet pulls up some data from web and updated. 2nd Sheet is analysis of the data in Sheet-1.

Now whenever I refresh data in sheet-1, the data in cells in Sheet-2 automatically refreshes. I want to stop this. I want to cells become inactive in Sheet-2 and thus don't have any impact of refresh and their values remains the same even after refresh.

How, is this possible? In other words, when I refresh I want to see the previous analysis and new analysis both. But when I refresh the same, the previous data is lost.

Comment: To eliminate the obvious, do you have cells in Sheet2 that depend on cells in Sheet1?

Answer (score 0):

Disable automatic calculation (file / options / formulas), i.e. choose "Manual calculation".
Activate the import sheet that loads data from web. Calculate (i.e. refresh) this sheet only (Menu: Formulas / Calculate Sheet).
Now, the import sheet should be up to date, but the second sheet should still show the old values.
To finally synchronize both sheets again, either activae automatic calculation, or just press  (forces workbook calculation incl. all sheets).

Comment: But this is an all time job. Every time I want to update the sheet, I have to do this process. Isn't there any other way to do this?

Comment: You can write a short VBA macro for this. It might be called e.g. from a custom button in the menu ribbon.